# "Stingy" tag and perhaps tags in general

Tags: discussion, tagging

I'm curious about the *stingy* tag.

Most of the ***tags*** on bicycles.stackexchange are reasonably obvious. The [stingy](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stingy) tag showed up when *[hhh](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/652/hhh)* joined the community.

I'm not opposed to the [*stingy*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1294440#m_en_us1294440) tag, but, a good definition would be useful. I'm not sure if the tag means: *[frugal?](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1249300#m_en_us1249300)* [*Cheap*?](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1232310#m_en_us1232310) Or perhaps: *bargain hunter*? A good definition behind this tag would really help when answering questions so tagged.

Beyond that, it seems that the tag wikis need work.

Comment: You can suggest tag wiki edits for any tag and mods or users over 1500 rep can [approve them](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits). You even get a little rep that way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree, I renamed it from [stingy](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stingy) to [frugal](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/frugal) since there is no need for the negative  connotations of the former.

Comment: "frugal" covers it nicely.

Answer (score 5):

['Stingy' may be perjorative (or self-deprecating)](http://www.google.ca/search?q=define%3Astingy), as well as being not-the-simplest-english-word-in-that-category: so I'd suggest maybe 'cheap' as the tag, instead.

After reading [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) you might decide that it's a meta-tag ...

- Describes the [intent of] the questioner, instead of describing the question
- Wouldn't be suitable to use as a question's only tag

... and therefore 'eradicate' it.

Comment: I agree that it is a borderline meta-tag, but if the overriding concern of the question is *I need to do this in the most inexpensive way imaginably possible* then I could perhaps defend its use -- removing the tag would change the question significantly.

Comment: Here's a good example of the frugal/cheap/stingy tag being used appropriately in a non-meta way: [Switching from 3x9 gears to cheaper ones](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2698/switching-from-3x9-gears-to-cheaper-ones).

Comment: @Jeff It's an adjective, not a noun or verb. It's a "dependent tag". It (the frugality motive) could have been just included in the question title and text; but maybe it adds value as a tag, also, e.g. because a hypothetical other user is more likely to want to search for 'frugal' than they are to want to search for 'homework' or 'subjective' (I'm not sure how they'd think/know to search for 'frugal' though, instead of e.g. 'cheap').

Answer (score 3):

The tags [stingy], [cheap], [inexpensive], and [low-cost] now are synonyms for [frugal]. So, if you use any of these as tags, they should remap to [frugal]. (I think that's how this works.)

Does this work for everyone? I'd much prefer to simply create synonyms than to mass-retag questions, since it bumps them up on the main site page as "modified".